# React component won't render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am doing freecodecamp and I am geting following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
I can't figure out where my mistake is. Here is code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
};

render(){
return(
  <div>
    <h1>My First React Component!</h1>
  </div>
);
};
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById('challenge-node'));
```

Comment: you have an extra };

Comment: I don't think that's it. Last } closes class and one before that closes render.

Comment: ah yes I thought you have 3 curly brackets closing instead if was 1 rounded brackets and 2 curly brackets. Props to rahuuzz, I would not have noticed the capitalization issue but always use console before posting to Stack Overflow as this would have been very clearly described in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be  `React.Component` and not  `React.component`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
};

render(){
return(
  <div>
    <h1>My First React Component!</h1>
  </div>
);
};
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById('challenge-node'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because of a simple typo in your code.

You have inputted `React.component` where is should be `React.Component`. I rectified that and the code works now.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My First React Component!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("challenge-node"));
```